# From within an object constructor, how can I append an attribute with a custom key value?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm working with an object prototype, and I'd like to append a new attribute onto an object during construction with a specific key but I can't figure out how to do that.

for example:

```
//define module prototype
Module = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        //simplified (static) example of a resource that 
        //would realistically be dynamically generated here
        //based on the arguments
        var resource = { 
            name: 'example name',
            value: 'string of text' 
        };

        // ! this line returns an an error that 'resources' is not defined
        // - this is supposed to be the definition of it. 
        this.resources[resource.name] = resource;
    }
};
```

My goal is for:

```
var exampleModule = new Module('exampleInput');
```

to return an object:

```
{
    resources : {
        'example name' : {
            //resource contents here
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully my question is clear - the problematic line where I try to append the attribute with a key is:

```
this.resources[resource.name] = resource;
```

Comment: You haven't defined this.resources yet.  `this.resources = {}; this.resources[resource.name] = resource;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
this.resources = {};
```

first, you can't add properties to an undefined reference.

Comment: Oh duh! Hahaha, too darn simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define resources as an object that is a property of Module before you can set its properties.  Add this before you enter the loop:

```
this.resources = {}
```